# How to add PPAs through a list?

Tags: command-line, apt, ppa, repository

I need to add PPAs on Ubuntu 14.04.3 from a file that contains a list of repositories, as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa: $ (cat ppas.list)
```

or

```
sudo add-apt-repository $ (cat ppas.list)
```

or yet

```
cat ppas.list | xargs sudo add-apt-repository
```

But these don't work and the following error appears: "Error: need a single repository as argument".

Can someone assist?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been cross-posted on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35003324/4316166

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works with the following command:

```
for i in $(cat ppas.list); do sudo add-apt-repository "$i"; done
```

Comment: I found the solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003324/how-to-add-ppas-through-a-list

Answer (score 8):

Use `-L1` to tell `xargs` to use only one input line per command:

```
cat ppas.list | xargs -L1 sudo add-apt-repository
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about that option. However you could also suggest to use the `-a` option of `xargs` instead of the useless `cat` (`xargs -a ppas.list -L1 sudo add-apt-repository`).

Comment: This will choke badly on whitespace(s) in the name..

Comment: @heemayl: Whitspaces aren't allowed in PPA names

Answer (score 3):

You could use a loop (and you'll probably want to add the `-y` option to the `add-apt-repository` command to avoid being prompted for a confirmation for each repository):

```bsh
while read x; do
    sudo add-apt-repository -y "$x"
done <file
```